# Is there any optimization options in AOSP when building applications which will remove classes that are not used?

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception, android-source

There is an android system application.

Some of it's classes are loaded (and must be loaded) by using Java interface Class.forName().

When the application is developing, we build it through eclipse and push the apk file to our device which flashed the eng version of OS.

This works, and the application runs normally.

After test, I copy the source code of the application to AOSP's packages/app/ directory and build it into OS.

Then, the issue appeared.

While running the application, it always throws `ClassNotFoundException`.

I tried to decompile the dex file which compiled in the apk file, and found that all classes which are not directly used (but loaded by Class.forName) are missing.

This likely some optimization options remove these classes from dex file.

*What we can do to disable these options to make my classes back?*

By the way, I found some of android platforms (eg. Allwinner A33 Android 4.4) have this issue, but others (eg. Mediatek MT6572 Android 4.4) are not.

Comment: Why you don't push your app to priv-apps?Do you use gradle in your eclipse to build the apk?

Comment: I pushed it to /system/app and it works. Now, I want to build it with the OS. I do not use gradle, I just use ADT(version 24.4.1) to build the apk.

Comment: Finally, I found it's ProGuard which cause this issue. On some of this platform, the default LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED is set to full, so classes, method and field which are not directly used will be optimised. On the other platform, this default value is set to disabled, the application worked normally. So, I just add LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled in my application's Android.mk file, which will prevent this issue happening.